# Google URL Safe Browsing(v4) lookup API is not working

Tags: email, postman, safe-browsing

We want to test the links given in the HTML email are safe or not. So we have been trying to use Safe Browsing Lookup API(V4) but it is giving empty JSON as response for unsafe URL too which was blocked in Chrome.

I am trying this API using PostMan and it is working fine for the URLs given in this example for testing Malware URLs - https://github.com/snopoke/google-safebrowsing2

I also tried with different threatTypes and platformTypes but unable to understand what is wrong in the request sent.

**Related screenshots**:

Success with test malware URL: https://snag.gy/Gt32JQ.jpg

Chrome browser blocked URL: https://snag.gy/jgaskh.jpg

Empty JSON through API: https://snag.gy/AoigpP.jpg

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have seen similar discrepancy between Google Safe-browsing API and Chrome/Firefox. Either the browsers have extra information, or they are not up to date in terms of removing entries when they are no longer malicious.

This particular entry is showing as phishing site by Fortinet on "virustotal.com" at the moment, so browsers may know this info from them.

Both my V4 and pre-V4 GSB lookup indicates its clean.

[virustotal showing site as phishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWuLI.png)
[Google safe browsing showing site as clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx9Ma.png)